# How can I implement the feature in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, popup, modalviewcontroller

[image: Here is screenshot]

**First Image**: This view contains 2 navigation bar with tableview. In the second navigation bar, there is one button.

**Second and Third Image**: When I click on the navigation button (second) one view will appear like this screenshot and according to the selected title will change on navigation.

Again I I select click on the navigation button, again view will appear and when we select an option according to that option tableview will changes.

What is that pop-up view, how to add or show tableview in that view, how to achieve this feature using Objective-C?

Comment: To achieve this popup you can create one transparent view and add simply table view on that. Here you need to set table view based on your required position like regular tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "popup view' in iOS is a UIAlertController: it has two subtypes: alert and action sheet. Then you need actions(those will represent each option in the actionsheet). Add each action to the action sheet then present it. Easy as that. Each action has a block that is executed when the action is selected. No need to show a tableCiew inside the actionsheet, it should stay as close to native as possible to keep the interface familiar to users. Refer to the [human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/action-sheets/) for more information.

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your message here" preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet ];
            UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"First item" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                NSLog(@"first item pressed");
            }];
            [actionSheet addAction:action];
            [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: ok, Andras, I will check this solution. What I want is that some custom changes in UIActionSheet like the screenshot in my question.

Comment: I used action sheet to achieve this. I got one custom library using this I achieved this. here is the link https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController